# Displaying images in rss description tag with php

Tags: php, html, xml, image, rss

I'm trying to display an image beside or before my description tag in my rss, I have tried on my localhost it worked like this:

```
<description><![CDATA[<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>">test test test test testtest test test test]]></description>
```

but on my website it's some kind different like this:

```
echo '
       <item>
          <title>'.$article[title].'</title>
          <description><![CDATA[<img src="$img_path">
          '.$shortdesc.'  
          ]]></description>
      </item>';
```

it's not working like this what is wrong in this ode? it's returnes blank iamge, here it's the page source from browser:

```
<description><![CDATA[<img src="$img_path">test test test</description>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP-code within single-quotes will not be parsed.

```
echo '
       <item>
          <title>'.$article['title']."</title>
          <description><![CDATA[<img src='{$img_path}'>
          ".$shortdesc.'  
          ]]></description>
      </item>';
```

or

```
echo '
       <item>
          <title>'.$article['title'].'</title>
          <description><![CDATA[<img src="'.$img_path.'">
          '.$shortdesc.'  
          ]]></description>
      </item>';
```

Comment: it;s returns this: "syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in"

Comment: Both of them returns this: <img src=''>

Comment: Then $img_path must be missing or empty inside your script.

Comment: Ow my GOD how is that passed on me, You were right it was blank, many thanks, now it works great